Confusion about the American English pronunciation of "latter"
In terms of American English, which one is correct pronunciation of "latter"? /ˈlætər/ or /ˈlʌtər/ or /ˈlɑːtər/? (Daniel Jones Phonetic Notation)
I googled it, and it is said that the correct pronunciation should be /ˈlætər/. However, it seems that it is pronounced differently from the /æ/ in ‘bad /bæd/’, ‘cat /kæt/’, or ‘have /hæv/’.
I'm a learner, and thanks for your answer!

Do you perceive it to be different from the vowel in "ladder"?

In my AmE dialect (Mid-Atlantic) the vowel of "bat" is more open than the vowel of "bad", and "latter" has the same vowel as "bat".  When I go to Dictionary.com, both the phonetic and IPA options give a southern American English pronunciation that is a near rhyme for "say it" spoken quickly with a palatal glide connecting the syllables.

@TimR I think the difference between "bat" and "bad" is because we draw the vowel out before the dull "d" sound (it's like "baaad"), but it's short before staccato "t".

@Barmar But that wouldn't explain AmE dialects where "bat" and "bad"  have the same vowel.

"I googled it, and it is said that the correct pronunciation should be /ˈlætər/. However, it seems that it is pronounced differently..." Please edit to tell more about how you get this impression. Right now my answer would be only "Yes, Google is right." I wonder whether you're encountering particular dialects? Or whether you're influenced by the timing of the syllable? If you've been listening to any particular speakers, please edit to tell about them.

It's pronounced just like the word "matter", but with an "l" instead of an "m."
